# Weird FluentAssertions behaviour with record classes

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have the following test that surprisingly passes:

```
abstract record class Base(string Property1);
sealed record class SubClassA(string Property1) : Base(Property1);
sealed record class SubClassB(string Property1, string Property2) : Base(Property1);
    
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var a = new SubClassA("test");
    var b = new SubClassB("test", "test");
    b.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a);
}
```

In the FluentAssertions [documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#value-types) it states that by default classes are compared using their members. How can this pass, since `SubClassB` clearly has one member more than `SubClassA`? I can make the test pass by changing to value semantics:

```
b.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a, options => options.ComparingRecordsByValue());
```

What is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Needs to be `a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);`

Comment: In other words, the expected value supplies all the items that are used for the comparison, and any items in the actual value that are not in the expected value are not considered in the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is telling FA to make sure that `b` is equivalent to `a`, and since `SubClassA` only has two properties, it will ignore the third property of `SubClassB`. In other words, the expectation drives the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still confused about the exact definition of equivalence in FA: two objects are considered "equivalent" if the intersection of members of the two objects return the same value?

Comment: @Ynv They are considered equivalent if all the public members of the expected value are the same as the corresponding members of the actual value. I would expect `Ynv is equivalent to a programmer` to be true, even if `Ynv` is also a father.

Comment: Thanks. Just one small thing: in the example `SubClassA` only has one property?